# A continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that has fixed points at $kn^2$ where $n$ is prime and $k$ is integer

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems

Can we find a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that has fixed points at $kn^2$ for every integer $k$ and every prime number $n$? And other points other than these are not fixed points? - this eliminates the case like $f(x)=x$.

It is also fine to slightly relax the condition and allow the set of fixed points to have numbers that are real numbers, but not integers.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why do you keep changing the question?

Comment: I am really sorry... It's not that I am changing my question - it's my words that failed to reflect my intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider the set $A=\{ kn^2\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}, \textit{n prime}}$ which is discrete and totally ordered so can be thought as $A=\{a_m\}$ and the set $B= \{\frac{a_m+a_{m+1}}{2} \}$ consisting of the points being in the middle of the points of $A$. Now you define the function that is $f(x)= x $ if $ x \in A$, $f(x)=x+1$ if $x \in B$ and is linear everywhere else.
 If $g(x)=x$, then it is clear that $f(x) \geq g(x)$ and equality holds only for $x \in A$.

Comment: But then is it really continuous? And not sure what "and is linear everywhere else" would mean... Does that mean that numbers not included in $A$ and $B$, f(x) would be linear....?

Comment: @fixed-point: You force the value at particular (discrete) points, both in $A$ and $B$. Now draw in the lines connecting the points in order.

Comment: As Clayton says, imagine you draw images for points in $A$ and $B$, now join those points by segments and you get the desired function. It is continuous by construction.

Comment: It makes no sense computing taylor series for a function that is not differentiable. Anyway, if you compute it in a neighbourhood of everypoint outside $A$ and $B$, then surely taylor series coincides with the function in that neighbourhood and all terms in the series but first and second will be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. $f(x)=x$ fixes every number, hence it fixes every number of the form $kn^2$.

Comment: I forgot to say that other numbers cannot be fixed numbers..

Comment: I'll keep thinking, but I'll leave this up for now (since it answered your original question).